# Moment timestamps === utc?

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

Are moment timestamps always in UTC? I did some play with the library, and moment(ts).unix() returns the same value as moment(ts).utc().unix().

Is there a way to get the local timestamp?

Comment: Timestamp values are always an offset from a fixed point in UTC time.

Comment: In particular, [*Unix Timestamps*](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) are from UTC.

Comment: UNIX timestamps are [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) always presented in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the Moment.js [front page](https://momentjs.com/):

```js
console.log(moment(1410715640579).format('LLL'))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```